# UITableview Scroll erases data in text field inside UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I have a UITableViewController with UITextfield inside the tableview cells. If I scroll the table view, the user entered data in the textfields disappears. I tried to add the textfield data to a NSMutableArray but it still didn't work. Any help please.

Comment: It's very hard to solve it without code.Try to give some code snippets over here.

Answer (score 4):

When `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called, the cell you return has to be completely filled in with whatever data you want to show. So, if the cell includes a UITextfield, you'll need to set it's `text` property to the right value for that row in your data.

When a table cell disappears off the top or bottom of the screen, the UITableViewCell itself becomes available for re-use. (As you scroll, cells disappear, and new cells appear, but the UITableView class is re-using the UITableViewCell objects.) In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when you get a cached cell to use, you have to be sure to setup everything you want it to show for the row in question, otherwise you might see some odd behavior in your table.

Does this help?

EDIT:

Here's an example of the typical pattern used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Notice the use of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. That method returns a previously allocated but not in use UITableViewCell, if there is one. Notice further that if no cached cell is returned, the code creates a new one, and sets it up (with stuff that is independent of anything that might be row specific). Following that, you'd setup the cell as you need it for the row in question.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *SearchResultsCellIdentifier = @"SearchResultsCellIdentifer";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
                dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SearchResultsCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                       reuseIdentifier:SearchResultsCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    // Your row-specific setup of the cell here
    // ...

    return cell;
}
```

Check the docs for specifics about these methods. There are LOTS of examples from Apple and elsewhere about how to implement tableViews.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I couldn'r understand this . - when you get a cached cell to use, you have to be sure to setup everything you want it to show for the row in question, otherwise you might see some odd behavior in your table. can u please make it more clear. Thanks

Comment: See the EDIT I added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I have done this. but my problem is the user enters data and when the UITableview cell is scrolled up, the user entered data in UItextfield disappears.

Comment: Ah! Ok. So you will need to implement the UITextFieldDelegate methods, and probably a UIScrollViewDelegate method to detect when the table is going to move so that if one of your text fields is active, you can save the text field value for use later (to fill in the text field when the cell reappears.)

Comment: Did u mean textfield didbeginediting and didendediting methods?

Comment: Yes, those are a couple of the UITextField delegate methods.