# UITableView clear the cell value when scroll off the screen

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have table view cell created from a nib file. There are different cells within tableview and to get input via keyboard I have to scroll tableview up the screen. Now problem is when I do that my cell value is cleared.

I know that cell is recreated when view goes off and on the screen but even worse is that my user defaults variable is null at that point and I get empty textfield.

To confirm the value is still in the user defaults, when I reload the application that value comes back.

This is how I am creating my tableviewcell

```
else if ([indexPath row] == 4)
{
    static NSString *WeeklyHoursCellIdentifier = @"WeeklyHoursCell";

    WeeklyHourTableViewCell *tempTextfieldcell = (WeeklyHourTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:WeeklyHoursCellIdentifier];
        if (tempTextfieldcell == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WeeklyHourTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            tempTextfieldcell = calculateTextFieldTableViewCell;
            self.calculateTextFieldTableViewCell = nil;
    }


    if ([prefs objectForKey:@"iPhoneWeeklyHours"] != nil) {
            tempTextfieldcell.textField.text = [prefs objectForKey:@"iPhoneWeeklyHours"];

        }
```

Any idea guys. I am really stuck here.

Thanks

Comment: Do you try to log values of `prefs`, `[prefs objectForKey:@"iPhoneWeeklyHours"]`?

Comment: Yes I tried that and it prints null.

Comment: This post should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807957/uitableview-scroll-erases-data-in-text-field-inside-uitableviewcell

Good luck,

Comment: prefs is not null but [prefs objectForKey:@"iPhoneWeeklyHours"] is null. which is weird because value is still there which comes back if I restart the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code is perfectly fine. I found bug in my code. I was assigning null to [prefs objectForKey:@"iPhoneWeeklyHours"] which is what I needed to avoid.

Thanks everyone for taking time to answer that.